# Continue Datatable iteration from middle of DataRows using C#

Tags: c#, oracle, datatable

I've a datatable of 100 or 200+ Rows (As Example considered 100 rows) with 3 columns. First column is Serial Number. Iterated the datatable upto second column value "Resources"  and Exit the datatable  foreach iteration after validation. Again need to start the datatable iteration from where iteration exited the row in middle of total datarows after "Resources" column. Datatable can have data beyond 100 or 200 rows also.

```
 bool status=false; int rownumber=0;
 foreach (DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
 {
     if (status)
     {
         rownumber = datatable.Rows.IndexOf(row);
          break;
     }

     foreach (DataColumn col in datatable.Columns)
     {
         //  Validation Logic

        if (row[col.ColumnName].ToString().Contains("Resources"))  // This row is dynamic. As example considered 50th row. 
            status = true;
     }                                                  
  }


// How to start iteration of datarow with same above datatable from ColumnName: "Resources" at 51st  row onwards? 
   
 // Below code is failing. System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Filter expression '51' does not evaluate to a Boolean term.'
 
 string selectedRow = datatable.Rows[rownumber][0].ToString(); 
 status=false;
 foreach (DataRow r in datatable.Select(selectedRow))
 {
     if (status)
     {
         rownumber = datatable.Rows.IndexOf(r);
          break;
     }

     foreach (DataColumn col in datatable.Columns)
     {
         // Next Validation Logic

        if (r[col.ColumnName].ToString().Contains("Resources"))                                
            status = true;
     }                                                  
  }
```

Comment: You can always use a standard for loop instead of a foreach

Comment: Above is example of 100 rows taken. sometimes data gets 200 or 300 or 500 rows also... But somewhere i stopped at column for a validation. Again wants to begin validation  after the column value "Resources"

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a row index for your logic then you can switch to a simple for...loop instead of a foreach one.

```
 bool status=false; 
 int rownumber=0;
 for(int x = 0; x < datatable.Rows.Count; x++)
 {
     DataRow row = datatable.Rows[x];
     if (status)
     {
         rownumber = x;
         break;
     }

     foreach (DataColumn col in datatable.Columns)
     {
         //  Validation Logic

        if (row[col.ColumnName].ToString().Contains("Resources"))                                
            status = true;
     }                                                  
  }
```

then

```
 status=false;
 rownumber++; // start from the next row if any
 for(int x = rownumber; x < datatable.Rows.Count; x++)
 {
     DataRow row = datatable.Rows[x];
     .... second loop logic ...
 }
```